# Creating and replying posts in teams from c#

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have a system that needs to send posts to teams. I can read that there is an implementation in BETA in  Microsoft Graph. However is there not any production SDK/API to do this? I dont expect us to be the first :D

Comment: connectors are a simple way to connect your web services to channels and teams inside Microsoft Teams. Could you please try connectors as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors)

Comment: If using a connector you could just as well just use the built in? Flow has a connector for posting and replying. But I would like a simple REST api so I can get the response instantly.

Comment: Currently we have graph [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)  in beta version. We do not have an ETA on when this will be production

Comment: Thanks I will follow. Hopefully soon :D